# Is this the correct way to expose a setting for a vb.net class library?

Tags: vb.net

I define in the Settings Tab of a VB.Net class library some user scoped settings. I want to expose these settings to other projects that reference the class library. I chose to do this using a public Module. This works, but it requires exposing each and every setting manually. Is there a better way?

```
Public Module Settings

    Public Property SomeSetting As Integer
        Get
            Return My.Settings.SomeSetting
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            My.Settings.SomeSetting = value
            My.Settings.Save()
        End Set
    End Property

End Module
```

Comment: You *could* expose the `Settings` module wholesale.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Can you elaborate?

Comment: Just have a (read-only) property which returns the `My.Settings` object (no setter required).

Comment: If you're going to expose getters *and* setters, you might as well make the settings `public`, no?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a fairly verbose way of exposing app settings. How about this?

[image]

<sub>(taken from an answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873656/how-to-make-application-properties-settings-public-and-stay-that-way))</sub>

This essentially comes down to what @KonradRudolph's comment was saying - the reason you "need" your `Settings` module is *probably* because the settings' access modifier is set to `Internal`, which means it's not accessible to other assemblies.

If you need to expose app settings to other assemblies, you just change that access modifier to `Public` and you're done.

Doing this:

```
Public Module Settings
    Public Property AppSettings As Settings
        Get
            Return My.Settings
        End Get
    End Property
End Module
```

Is then totally redundant. Even more so, doing what you've done (exposing each setting individually) becomes more painful to maintain than it needs to be; if the settings are public then you expose the settings class itself and whatever you change is immediately available to client assemblies.